# Back in UINavigationItem making problem

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

i have problem that i have 3 views,

i goto first view to 2nd and want to change mine back button title

i write this code in viewDidLoad of 2nd View but its not working :(

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:nil action:nil];

[self.navigationItem setBackBarButtonItem:backButton];
```

Comment: Is the code you've supplied in your viewDidLoad method?  Also, check that navigationItem is non-null, add this code to the code above:   NSLog(@"navItem: 0x%x",self.navigationItem);

Comment: no its not null following are the log: navItem: 0x7233a40, and yes we supplied this in 2nd view vieDidLoad Method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

go to 1st view controller and add the following code before you push the viewController,

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Inv Menu" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

Comment: thanks that work.. !! i did the same thing but i did 2 mistake that i have done this after alloc and before navigation .. but now i did before alloc and 2nd mistake I also i did do that i write not self i write the object name which i alloc ... !! but this work .. i got it what i did wrong. Thanks @MacDev.... Thanks soo much